# yolo cost function

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, object-detection, yolo

[image]

At the output of the final layer of yolo, a leaky-relu is applied to the output, so if we have negative values for the width and height, the cost function will return a null value since we would have square rooted a negative value at the second sum of the cost. Thus not able to update the weights using back prop.

Am I wrong about this or is there something I am missing here? If I am not wrong, how do we guarantee the width and height to be positive?

Comment: You are summing squared values; The sum will be at worst 0, assuming lambdas are positive.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs Sorry I don't see how that solves my problem, the square root would have still returned an imaginary value if the inside is negative, and if I do have an object in the cell, the term is not gonna become zero.

Comment: You asked "how do we guarantee the output to be positive" and I understood it that way, how to prove the expression you wrote is positive. I apologize for having misunderstood your question.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs Thanks for your response, I will edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [source code](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/cd5d393b46b59dc72a5150436e70fa91a2918b2d/src/region_layer.c#L81), actually they use an `exp` operation to ensure $w$ and $h$ are non-negative values.

```
box get_region_box(float *x, float *biases, int n, int index, int i, int j, int w, int h, int stride)
{
    box b;
    b.x = (i + x[index + 0*stride]) / w;
    b.y = (j + x[index + 1*stride]) / h;
    b.w = exp(x[index + 2*stride]) * biases[2*n]   / w;
    b.h = exp(x[index + 3*stride]) * biases[2*n+1] / h;
    return b;
}
```

Here `w` and `h` are width and height of the network input, `b.w` and `b.h` are normalized width and height of the bonding box, `x` is last layer's output. It's not very clear what `biases` are though.

Comment: That's actually the same trick used in getting the standard deviation of a variational autoencoder. I don't get why they don't just use a normal relu though

Comment: @ChesterCheng yes relu will do the same but it won't get any gradient if the input is negative, actually other functions that maps a real number to a positive number would work as well for example $x^2$ and $log(1+exp(x))$.

Comment: you are right! I guess they chose exp cus of the simple derivative

Answer (score 0):

> if we have negative values for the width and height

As in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640), the bounding box size is normalised between 0 and 1, hence will not be negative.

[image]